# Mapping value to compatible function creates uncallable function union

Tags: typescript

I have to deal with ingesting one of many possible values, but within those values there is an id which can be used to get the correct `change` function. With typescript, however this does not work because the union of all functions is not callable.

```js
type Module<T> = {
  change: (value: T) => void
}
enum ModuleID {
  A = "id:A",
  B = "id:B"
}
interface Identifiable<ID extends ModuleID> {
  id: ID
}
// Module A
interface A extends Identifiable<ModuleID.A> {
  item: 'value:A'
}
export const moduleA: Module<A> = {
  change(a: A) {}
}
// Module B
interface B extends Identifiable<ModuleID.B> {
  item: 'value:B'
}
export const moduleB: Module<B> = {
  change(a: B) {}
}
// Map id to module containing the correct `change` function
const moduleMap = {
  [ModuleID.A]: moduleA,
  [ModuleID.B]: moduleB
}
// While conceptually correct, this does not work with typescript
function changeValue(value: A | B) {
  const module = moduleMap[value.id]
  // The intersection 'A & B' was reduced to 'never' because 
  // property 'item' has conflicting types in some constituents.
  module.change(value)
}
```

How could I restructure this so that I can call the appropriate `change` method based on the value's `id` in a type-safe way.

Comment: The issue is [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the fix is going to be to do as in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) but I don't have time to do the refactoring right now... hope to get to it soon

Comment: All right, [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N9j41m) shows the requisite refactoring; does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue I call *correlated unions*, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Inside the body of `changeValue()`, the type of `module.change` and the type of `value` are both [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), but the compiler is unable to model the *correlation* between them. If the compiler could narrow `value` first to `A` and then to `B`, it would be happy:

```
function changeValue(value: A | B) {
  if (value.id === ModuleID.A) {
    const module = moduleMap[value.id]
    module.change(value) // okay
  } else {
    const module = moduleMap[value.id]
    module.change(value) // okay
  }
}
```

But it can only do so via different [control flow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis), which is not what you want to do, since it's redundant and scales in redundancy with the input union.  It can't look at a single line of code and evaluate it for each narrowing at once.

---

The recommended solution for dealing with correlated unions is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), and involves refactoring the types so that you use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead of unions, and that the generic operations are written explicitly in terms of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) such types.  The goal is that `changeValue()` should be generic in some keylike type `K`, such that `value` is seen of type `F<K>` for some `F`, and `module.change` is seen of type `(value: F<K>) => void` for the same `F`.  This will allow the call.

Here's one way to do it. First let's make a type in which we can look up the argument type for `change()` based on the `ModuleID`:

```
type Modules = A | B;
type ChangeArg = { [M in Modules as M['id']]: M }
/* type ChangeArg = {
  "id:A": A;
  "id:B": B;
} */
```

Then we will write the type of `moduleMap` explicitly as a mapped type on this:

```
const moduleMap: { [K in ModuleID]: Module<ChangeArg[K]> } = {
  [ModuleID.A]: moduleA,
  [ModuleID.B]: moduleB
}
```

And finally, we will make `changeValue` generic in `K`, the type of the `ModuleID` involved:

```
function changeValue<K extends ModuleID>(value: Identifiable<K> & ChangeArg[K]) {
  const _value: Identifiable<K> = value;
  const module = moduleMap[_value.id]
  module.change(value)
}
```

That needs some explanation; in order for this to work, the compiler needs to understand that `value` is an `Identifable<K>` so that `value.id` is of type `K`, and also that `value` is of type `ChangeArg[K]` so that its seen as a valid input to `moduleMap[value.id]`.  This turns out to be a little tricky, so I help the compiler along by defining `value`'s type as the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of those two types (even though `ChangeArg[K]` is already a subtype of `Identifiable<K>` for every `K`), and then widening to `Identifiable<K>` before getting its `id` property (so the compiler keeps it generic as `K` and doesn't widen to something less usable).

You can verify that `module.change` is now seen as type `(value: ChangeArg[K]) => void`, which accepts an argument of type `Identifiable<K> & ChangeArg[K]`, and so the body of `changeValue()` compiles without error.

---

Let's also make sure that callers still have reasonable behavior:

```
changeValue({ id: ModuleID.A, item: 'value:A' }); // okay
changeValue({ id: ModuleID.A, item: 'value:B' }); // error
changeValue({ id: ModuleID.B, item: 'value:B' }); // okay
changeValue({ id: ModuleID.B, item: 'value:A' }); // error
```

Looks good!

---

Finally, it might not be worth the time/effort/complexity to you to refactor this way.  It's perfectly reasonable for you to just leave your code as-is and just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the warning, as long as you're convinced that it's correct:

```
const module = moduleMap[value.id] // Module<A> | Module<B>
module.change(value as never); // I know this line is fine so leave me alone
```

Which way you proceed depends on what's more important for your use case: if you want compiler-verified type safety and don't care about complexity then refactoring might be the way to go; if you want compiler-verified type safety but without the complexity, you might want to do the narrowing via redundant control flow.  And if you care less about compiler-verified type safety that making forward progress, then an assertion might be your solution.  It's up to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLIBCIAJnkSSQC4CeMyAsgPa0CuGCAB4AKgD4kAXgbEmJeAAsQwAOYQAXEgAUAN0x8NSEQEopEndwCWtRkwC+tkhGB8wSHv0EBJACIy5JACCUkgARNbqgaEANI5MVCHhtOpUoXEOsiSWwMwQAE4AZpRIXrTOzJYFliAARoJCvkgQAB65wLRQ7rwCEL4SBJlMESU+6XEA9ONdnsiBcdm5hcXBLW0dJWU5ldV1wh49vgB0gf1xWblgmgDkehgGkVdjgy0w3HnMSPDcwFAfYN2CQKafb1E4hAYBT5KVQQLQgTSBUy4JAZOSopiTaY9JBUeY5fJFRA4pqtZzrUrlba1eog3o+Q5UU6Dc4QS5IG76DRUR6DdFOZqvd6fb6-JD-GZUYEA4SM8FnKHKNRwzRUJEop5yTGcEAwJDWJDMbhi6XCnIgbLZFQGhTIL55PIQeAfAAGikVEGdSAKfGATss3ziXx+f2l2t10ghAQA2rSjoEALqacU9QKxZlIGPSo5URPGiUapje30Vb4KmEANU5uk5CKQAB8cUj5UHRcnBCE2xAw1HbgZDtZ40gtdKhGCG7ShIz5Z3Dm6YdW7sgQJ1gBAdPljABuIdTABWfFFy6g+WYRHllW0vYg-fokjvWO89MR-khptbJukne7V5v8flJBnOclSvYx5TsJoMGPF9IRbEMZg7UMdR7Tlf3-PMelnaFgM5UD0z5dVZAyWwyGgOAiQAcW4XgZDiNgOAfYRxDldMgMMBd7iMUxJHMKwbF5OJnFcBjGkjORgmkJJIhieUEgkiJUieM9BgWAligpLYqmpYRGlWMlOljHwmUhYZfALEhh3guZlPxJYiRWUl2k6dSKk03YhAM44jICSwLmuK8HjMklBQ+WD0MBKUZlHCQI2bLDYXhJBn2RfCiMGCzsVxazFkJagSTWJzNhcnYaSzelZVEoZfPZfzuUCl43hCkU4J6SUGMnaLoKYVjlUbPACLRJTaPYLhpU6aRggbKhNyG+iAGE4sCPIrQjDNOD1YAGM6Zd3CjK5rCueNczW-DxgAKgNYakHm91FuWzqSEkqIEWm9NJNSFUXrRJBTvGJS5FCr8dU0ZEowAaXW4SfCOkdrphW6wfjCRwJi9NMxmONc07VN5TRg4ysx6VMoGwg4iLP1S1YytFyEcHdMcyGxHYwxnKpNzQYkAAyK6FqWhGmxYpqkAAfX8jZKVc+p2ZCK9PoCAGPzCrskJFlCB2naVMPdJnTExLQ4DycAIEWUxRZZiXhClrnYbUeHQb-dNMV1mA8m4Dh3lYUxWM0JnNGtiBbfjLieOsRTBkpqtkWGDzUz1KqOUXB4US3HckG4ABrEBWEDOKqYMLRI+SSHjmiWPWT8mtuST7dMXyF28mz91c9hAuIrxhkS58svqorq4q5T9PM4bisI71QuPKoDu4-8wJe7sZOa-tN4-oIog7CAA)